# bootstrap carousel how to move by one item

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap carousel in my [WP theme](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/partneri), but the whole slider is moving by four items, how I would achive to move them one by one infinite loop? I've tried just to copy [this solution](http://www.bootply.com/94452) and only the first item was visible.

Here is my code for now:

```
 <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="partneri-carousel">                          
        <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-3 column text-center">
             <div class="logo">
                 <img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cvicny_partner2.png">
                 </div>
                 <div class="popisek">Simona je nkjnaskndkjsan bjhdbasjhbdjhba snhjqbsjwqb sbjqwbsq dbjudwzgzd</div>
                 <div><a href="http://www.kybernaut.cz" target="_blank">www.kybernaut.cz</a></div>                                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 column text-center">
                 <div class="logo">
                 <img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cvicny_partner.png">
                 </div>
                 <div class="popisek">You can re-order with drag & drop, the order will update after saving.</div>
                 <div><a href="http://www.kybernaut.cz" target="_blank">www.kybernaut.cz</a></div>                                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 column text-center">
                 <div class="logo">
                 <img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cvicny_partner2.png">
                 </div>
                 <div class="popisek">www.kybernaut.czwww. kybernaut.czwww. kybernaut. czwww.kybernaut.cz</div>
                 <div><a href="http://www.kybernaut.cz" target="_blank">www.kybernaut.cz</a></div>                                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 column text-center">
                 <div class="logo">
                 <img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cvicny_partner.png">
                 </div>
                 <div class="popisek">Pokud chcete použít toto uživatelské jméno, klikněte na tlačítko</div>
                 <div><a href="http://www.kybernaut.cz" target="_blank">www.kybernaut.cz</a></div>                                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-3 column text-center">
                 <div class="logo">
                 <img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cvicny_partner2.png">
                 </div>
                 <div class="popisek">uživatelské jméno, klikněte na tlačítko Pokud chcete použít toto </div>
                 <div><a href="http://www.kybernaut.cz" target="_blank">www.kybernaut.cz</a></div>                                  
            </div>
        </div>                            
    </div>

        <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/themes/sb/images/arr_simple_left.png" alt="arr_simple_left"></a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/themes/sb/images/arr_simple_right.png" alt="arr_simple_right"></a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#partneri-carousel').carousel({
    pause: "hover",
    interval: 4000,
  });
});</script>
```

What I want to achieve is following:
(numbers represents "partner box", "=>" one move of carousel, having for ex. six partner's boxes)
1 2 3 4 => 2 3 4 5 => 3 4 5 6 => 4 5 6 1 => 5 6 1 2 => infinite loop

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap slides are defined as elements with the class "item", which is why your first four "items" are moving - they are actually a single item.

Sample "single" item:

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="col-3 column text-center">
   <div class="logo">
     <img src="http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cvicny_partner2.png">
     </div>
     <div class="popisek">Simona je nkjnaskndkjsan bjhdbasjhbdjhba snhjqbsjwqb sbjqwbsq dbjudwzgzd</div>
     <div><a href="http://www.kybernaut.cz" target="_blank">www.kybernaut.cz</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code above also doesn't reference the carousel properly in the controls.

I've tidied up your markup in this fiddle, which hopefully does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/davidcw/k1jnj15b/

Good luck!

### Edit: Dynamically Set Number of Items in WordPress

Sorry, I misunderstood.
You can do what you need by closing & opening divs based on whether or not your images are a multiple of your target number (in this case 4). Start a counter, and use something like this `if( $i % $slidenumber == 0 && $i < $rowcount)` to determine whether the item div should be closed.

This code or similar should go into your `.carousel-inner` div:

```
<?php

    $i = 1;
    //added before the while loop to ensure the div gets opened
    echo "<div id='item-$i' class='item'><ul class='carousel-thumbnails'>";

    $rowcount = count( get_field('carousel_images')); // the total number of images - counts rows in the ACF repeater array, so you may need a different method of counting rows.

        while( has_sub_field('carousel_images') ){

             /*===========================================================*/
             $slidenumber = 4; // SET NUMBER OF SLIDES HERE
             /*===========================================================*/
             $thumb_id = get_sub_field('image');
             $thumbsize = "thumbnail"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
             $thumbimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, $thumbsize );

             ?>
              <li>
                 <img src="<?php echo $thumbimage[0]; ?>" />
              </li>
              <?php

         // if multiple of $slidenumber close div and open a new div
         $itemNumber = ($i / $slidenumber) + 1;

         if( $i % $slidenumber == 0 && $i < $rowcount) {

           echo "</ul></div><div id='item-$itemNumber' class='item'><ul class='carousel-thumbnails'>";

            }

        $i++;

        };

    //make sure open div is closed
    echo "</ul></div>";

    ?>
```

The markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="thumb-carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <!--
        PHP block from above goes here
        -->
      </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumb-carousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumb-carousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will also need to dynamically add the active class to the first carousel item, so that the carousel initiates. You can do this with the following jQuery:

```
(function( $ ) {'use strict';
  $(function() {
    // Give active class to the first thumbnail item (block of images)
    $("#thumb-carousel .item:first").addClass("active");
  });
})( jQuery );
```

For the sake of completeness, you need to add some CSS rules to make the images (which are in a ul) display properly. So for the example above, you need:

```
ul.carousel-thumbnails {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 78px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-thumbnails li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that's not what I wanted. I understand moving single item, but I need to achvieve [this](http://www.bootply.com/94452) but unfortunately in wordpress it makes only [this result](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/dgsimona/pokus/) and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: thanks for your helo, but I've got lost on my way to implement it. I have following code, which I'm not sure how to change it, could you have a look there? [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kMYaL30Y)

Comment: I've cloned and edited your pastebin - http://pastebin.com/6b5ik0u4 This should work - if it's ok let me know and I'll amend my answer for sake of completeness. The main problem was that you needed to open your item before looping through your images.

Comment: That works same way as the old my version. That what I want is to see following (numbers represents "partner box", "=>" one move of carousel, having for ex. six partner's boxes):
1 2 3 4 => 2 3 4 5 => 3 4 5 6 => 4 5 6 1 => 5 6 1 2 => infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the moveSlides parameter? I dont know the script you're using, but the code reads like it does just that.

(Im sorry I cant post such a vague answer as comment, my reputation isnt high enough for that)

Comment: No problem. I'm using the default bootstrap carousel. I don't know about bootstrap having this parameter. If you advice different carousel, it would be probably as well ok.